# Mouse/gesture control with kinect?

Tags: mouse, gestures

I'm lazy and i know it... but I am looking for either a debian package or a set of terminal commands that will:

- Download kinect drivers
- enable me to control the mouse with Kinect

Is there any one out there that knows if this has been done or can do it?

Answer (score 2):

**Multi-touch**

> It’s  powered by something called
>   [TISCH](http://tisch.sourceforge.net/) (Tangible Interactive Surfaces
>   for Collaboration between Humans)
>   which now has a PPA with support for
>   Kinect baked in.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:floe/libtisch
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libtisch libtisch-dev libtisch-csharp libtisch-java libtisch-python
```

[Video Link](http://www.youtube.com/embed/ho6Yhz21BJI?html5=1&eurl=http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/multi-touch-in-ubuntu-using-kinect-video-ppa/)

[Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/multi-touch-in-ubuntu-using-kinect-video-ppa/)

Comment: Thats for that. I ran the commands in the terminal but... now what. I don't really know how to get it working... any tips?

Comment: connected your kinect ?

Comment: Ooh... So I guess I have the kinect drivers installed (I have run the above in terminal) but how do I get it up and running so that my curser is controlled by the kinect (it is connected to the computer)? I can say that I have a fresh install of 11.04.

Answer (score 2):

I found this:

https://github.com/Ooblik/Kinect-Mouse

P.S: Seems pretty straight forward. I wonder is there anyone our there that wants to make a .deb file with a GUI for systemsettings??? :-)

Comment: Same installation but more detailed instructions: http://sharpeespace.blogspot.com/2011/03/connect-microsoft-kinect-to-ubuntu.html